# If $x^4 =x$ in a ring, then the ring is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ring such that $x^4=x$ for all $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76792/ring-such-that-x4-x-for-all-x)

Let $R$ be a ring such that $a^4=a$ $  ,\forall a \in R$.
How do I show that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/is-such-ring-commutative

Comment: I answered this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76792/ring-such-that-x4-x-for-all-x/77016#77016

Answer (score 1):

If 2 is invertible, it may work this way:

For arbitrary elements $a,b$ calculate $ab-ba = (ab-ba)^4 = (ba-ab)^4 = ba-ab$. So $2ab=2ba$ and hence $ab=ba$.

Comment: 2 cannot be invertible, right? Otherwise, for any $a\in R$, $a=a^4=(-a)^4=-a$. So $2a=0$, which implies $a=0$.

Comment: you are totally right, thanks. So the above is useless.

Comment: no, it's a good try. I think it's not easy to prove it, maybe I am not good at algebra.