# A ring with $x^3=x$ for all $x$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Property of commutative rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/property-of-commutative-rings)

Show a simple proof that if $R$ is a ring such that $x^{3}=x$ for all $x\in R$ then $R$ is commutative. (You don't need the Jacobson radical, I'll provide proof if this remains unanswered too long.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/property-of-commutative-rings, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/is-such-ring-commutative http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76792/ring-such-that-x4-x-for-all-x

Comment: Only one of the links above is a duplicate. The others consider related problems such as $\, x^n = x\:$ for $\:n = 4,5,\:$ whose proofs *do not* apply to this case.