# Rings with $a^5=a$ are commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, automated-theorem-proving

**Update.** I have generalized the method here and have shown the theorem for many more exponents: [Equational proofs of Jacobson's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301)

---

Let $R$ be a ring such that $a^5=a$ for all $a \in R$. Then it follows that $R$ is commutative.

This is part of a more general well-known theorem by [Jacobson](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205)  for arbitrary exponents ($a^n=a$), which appeared on math.stackexchange [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/) [couple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360958/) [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/) [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10274). But what I would like to see is a proof which is (1) direct / elementary and  (2) in equational language (in particular, first-order). (As far as I know, [no](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077465581) [published](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-4/2/331.extract) [proof](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02993501) of Jacobson's Theorem is equational, but such a proof [has to exist](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33234/2841)). See [here](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/rings-satisfying-x3-x-are-commutative/) and [there](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/rings-satisfying-x4-x-are-commutative/) for such proofs for the exponents $3$ and $4$. I hope that these proofs make the "rules" clear.

What I've done so far: Reduced to the case that $R$ has characteristic $5$. Any element of the form $a^4$ is central, [because](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/about-reduced-rings-1/) it is idempotent and $R$ is reduced. Also, it suffices to prove $(ab)^2= b^2 a^2$ for $a,b \in R$. In fact, this implies
$$ab=(ab)^5=a(ba)^4 b = (ba)^4 ab  = b a b (ab)^2 a^2 b$$
$$ = b a b (b^2 a^2) a^2 b  = b a b^3 a^4 b  = b a a^4 b^3 b  = b a b^4  = b b^4 a = ba.$$
Perhaps someone can feed automatic theorem provers with this problem. But my experience is that their proofs are not so easy to follow, quite long and not intuitive. So I am actually looking for hand-made proofs which eventually might also work for rings satisfying $a^p=a$ where $p$ is any prime.

*Edit.* Here is some progress, inspired by the [proof](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02993501) by Nagahara and Tominaga. Consider $a \in R$ and decompose the finite commutative reduced ring $\langle a \rangle$ into a product of fields - this is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Hence, $a=a_1+\dotsc+a_n$ where each $\langle a_i \rangle$ is a field with unit $e_i=a_i^4$. The only fields satisfying the equation are $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_5$, which are *prime fields*. Hence, $a_i = z_i e_i$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ is central and therefore $a$ is central. (This incredibly quick proof for the $(a^n=a)$-problem works for all exponents $n$ where every prime power $q$ such that $q-1|n-1$ is actually a prime number.)

*2nd Edit*. This leads to an equational proof. For simplicity, let us assume that $R$ has characteristic $5$.  (This reduction is not in equational language, but the cases of characteristic $2$ and $3$ can be dealt separately and in the end everything may be put into a single equational proof.) Then $\langle a \rangle$  is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_5[T]/(T^4-1)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_5 \times \mathbb{F}_5 \times \mathbb{F}_5 \times \mathbb{F}_5$ via $f \mapsto (f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4))$. We can compute the corresponding idempotents:
$$e_1 = (t-2)^2 (t-3)(t-4), e_2 = (t-1) (t-3) (t-4)^2, \\e_3 = (t-1)^2 (t-2) (t-4), e_4 = (t-1) (t-2) (t-3)^2.$$
Back in $R$ we obtain the equation
$$a = e_1(a) + 2 e_2(a) + 3 e_3(a) + 4 e_4(a).$$
Each $e_i(a)$ is idempotent, hence central, and therefore $a$ is central. This proof may be carried out in equational language - but then we would have to verify the equation and that the $e_i(a)$ are idempotent, which is obviously *very* tedious.

Is there also a proof which is (3) not tedious?

Comment: The paper "Automated Proof of Ring Commutativity Problems by Algebraic Methods" by H. Zhang (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771710880020X) looks very promising, at least for the case that the exponent is even. A little bit is said about the case of $5$, however not enough (in particular, the mentioned equalities are trivial in characteristic $5$). Does someone have access to "Prove ring commutativity problems by algebraic methods" (1989) by the same author? This seems to have more details.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153876/29335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a really smart proof in [these notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ggim/W14-110BH.pdf) by Geunho Gim.

*Lemma*. In a reduced ring, if $e^2=ze$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $ze$ is central.

*Proof*: For a given element $x$, expand $(exe-zex)^2$, it evaluates to zero. Hence, $exe=zex$. Similarly, $exe=xze$. $\square$

*Theorem.* If $R$ is a ring in which every element $x$ satisfies $x^5=x$, then $R$ is commutative.

*Proof.* Let $x \in R$. Then $(x^4+x^2)^2=x^8+2x^6+x^4=2(x^4+x^2)$, hence $2(x^4+x^2)$ is central by the Lemma. Since $x^4$ is idempotent, it is central by the Lemma. Hence, $2x^2=2(x^4+x^2)-2 x^4$ is central. But then $4x^3=2(x^2+x)^2-2x^4-2x^2$ is central. It follows that
$$2x^3+x^2+5x=(x^2+x)^5-(x^2+x) - 10 x^4 - 2 (4 x^3) - 2(2x^2)$$
is central. Therefore
$$7x^4+4x^3 + 8x^2 + 11x = 2(x^2+x)^3 + (x^2+x)^2+5(x^2+x)$$
is central, too. Finally, we see that
$$x = (7x^4+4x^3+8x^2+11x)-7x^4 - 3(2x^2)- 2(2x^3+x^2+5x)$$
is central. $\square$

Comment: Another proof (actually for all $n \leq 25$ odd and all even $n \leq 50$) appears in Y. Morita, Elementary proofs of the commutativity of rings satisfying $x^n=x$, Memoirs Def. Acad. Jap. XVIII (1978), 1-23.

Comment: How does the second to the last equation follow? I mean, how do we know that each term in the right hand side is in the center?

Comment: In fact, how do we even show that $4x^3$ is central? How do we know that $2(x^2+x)^2$ is central?

Comment: @user134070 substitute $x^2 + x$ everywhere you see an $x$ on the LHS of the preceding line. although now that i look, you asked this five and a half years ago, so you've probably moved on :)